# What kind of JavaScript is $.getJSON()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.getJSON(getUrl, params,
    function (jsonData) {
        $("#verifyCode").removeClass("bcB").addClass("bcC");
        if (jsonData.resultCode == '0000' || jsonData.resultCode > 1 && jsonData.resultCode < 6) {
            window.location = jsonData.redirectURL;
            return;
        } else if (jsonData.resultCode == '8008' || jsonData.resultCode == '8013' || jsonData.resultCode == '8014' || jsonData.resultCode == '8007') {
            $("#verifyCodeError").show().html("wrong user name");
            $("#password").val('');
            $("#verifyCode").val('');
            $("#password").focus();
        } else if (jsonData.resultCode == '8023') {
            $("#verifyCodeError").show().html("verify code is wrong");
            $("#verifyCode").val('');
            $("#verifyCode").focus();
        }
```

what's the usage of this javascript?
**$.getJSON** is not jquery usage,can anyone give me some tips.
and **function(jsonData)**,how to pass the jsonData to the function?

Comment: `$.getJSON` _is_ a jQuery function

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: I'm not sure if you've posted the complete thing. There is, at least, a `}` and `);` missing from the end of that - it won't compile as is.

Comment: Well the objection is reasonable, maybe OP is used just to `$(selector).someFunction()` notation. `$.someFunction`is just some DOM-unrelated function lying in jQuery namespace, that's it.

Comment: @moonwave99: The *first Google result* for "$.getJSON" is http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: @PaulD.Waite yes of course, I am just stating that that may not seem _jQuery usage_. Of course should he have researched on his own ; ))

Comment: lian sorry,it's not laziness,but I don't know much about javascript and think it's not a reasonbale usage.thx

Comment: @young001: it probably was more effort to type the question into Stack Overflow than Google "$.getJSON", so in that sense it's not lazy, but you should have searched first. See the very first point on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

> **$.getJSON** is not jquery usage

Wrong.
That [is a function](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L678) provided by jQuery.

---

> **function(jsonData)**,how to pass the jsonData to the function?

That is an asynchronous callback.
`$.getJSON()` calls it when the response arrives.

Answer (score 0):

The jsonData is being passed to the function by the getJSON function.

API Docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/